# new Response(decompressedStream).blob() results in "Failed to fetch"?

Tags: javascript, streams-api

I am trying to make it so that if a zip file is chosen from a file dialog, it will unzip it and pass the unzipped result to the `readAsDataURL` method.  However whenever I choose a zip file to do this, I get:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Below is a snippet you can run, open your web inspector, and try selecting a local .zip file.

```js
const unzip = async (blob) => {
  let stream = new DecompressionStream('deflate');
  const decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(stream);
  return await new Response(decompressedStream).blob();
};

const opener = document.getElementById('open');
opener.addEventListener('change', async () => {
  let [file] = opener.files;
  if (!file) { return; }
  
  if (file.type === 'application/zip') {
    file = await unzip(file);
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const data = reader.result.split(',')[1];
    console.log('your contents are', data);
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="open" type="file" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `DecompressionStream` isn't meant to work with zip archives directly, you'd need to extract each files from the archive and use a *deflate-raw* algo on it. That's still a lot of work. See [this article](https://dev.to/ndesmic/writing-a-simple-browser-zip-file-decompressor-with-compressionstreams-5che) that I didn't review but seems legit enough.